# Mettere/Stare a proprio agio in una parola

Tags: single-words, synonym

Come si può dire "quella persona si trova a proprio agio" o "ho messo quella persona a proprio agio" in una parola/aggettivo?

Tipo, "quella persona è xxx" per dire "quella persona si trova a proprio agio".

Comment: Non credo ci sia un’unica parola per dirlo.

Comment: Potrebbe essere accomodare? Quella persona è accomodata, ad esempio

Comment: @abarisone grazie per il suggerimento ma accomodata in questo contesto non l'ho proprio mai sentita

Comment: Quella persona sta comoda?

Comment: Io direi... “quella persona si trova a proprio agio”. :)

Comment: @Charo sì, è il meglio che ho pensato anche io, anche se ha un significato un po' diverso. Sembra allora che non ci sia una parola sola che abbia lo stesso significato.

Comment: Probabilmente se non c'è un termine singolo generalmente valido almeno ci saranno vari termini adatti alle varie situazioni. Prova a fornire dei contesti nella domanda (es. I vestiti mi stavano stretti, ora grazie alla dieta mi sento più a mio agio --> comodo, altro es. Finché ero disoccupato mi sentivo inadeguato a cena dai suoceri, ora mi sento a mio agio --> tranquillo, apprezzato)

Answer (score -1):

Come hanno scritto @abarisone e @Charo nei commenti, in una sola parola puoi dire **comodo**.
Per fare un esempio calzante con le tue richieste:

> - quella persona è comoda (= sta bene, è a suo agio)
> - ho fatto si che quella persona stesse comoda (= stesse a suo agio)
> - Sono comodo (= sono a mio agio)

Spero possa esserti utile.